# How to call a function for 3 different lists of different sizes without using multiple for loops?

Tags: python, list

I have a function which will split the file name. I want to call the function on 3 different filename lists (`filenames_list1`, `filenames_list2`, `filenames_list3`) of different sizes. So instead to using 3 `for` loops to call the function on 3 different list, is there a method in python to improve the performance of my code? When I run the code on large data for loops are taking a lot of time.

My code:

```
def split(file_name, list1, list2, list3 ):
    list1.append(file_name.split('_')[-3])
    list2.append(file_name.split('_')[-2])
    list3.append(file.split('/')[-2])

for i in filenames_list1:
    split(i, a_list, b_list, c_list )

for i in filenames_list2:
    split(i, d_list, e_list, f_list )

for i in filenames_list3:
    split(i, k_list, l_list, m_list )
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: No, there is no method to speed up what you are doing.

Comment: You can use something that isn't a for loop, but it isn't going to improve the performance. Because in the end, you still loop *somehow*, even if it is hidden in a `map` or whatever. The looping is not actually your bottleneck. On my machine, a for loop, just `for i in range(10_000_000): pass` is almost instantanous

Comment: If you are looking for ways to improve your code, rather than make it work, then codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place. Trying to create a concise question for an open-ended goal is probably not going to give you all info you want. Make sure you read the site guidelines there first though, they are a bit different from those here.

Comment: While you won't get any performance boost by changing the way you loop, you're splitting the string with `_` 2 times. Store the result of `file_name.split('_')` to a variable and index it 2 times. That is going to optimize your code a bit.

Comment: you can't make it faster using different method to loop it. You have to optinize code in your `split()` - ie. you could use `rsplit` instead of `split` and use parameter `rsplit(.., number)` to split only last 3 element. And you could run split with `'_'` only once. And if you have big lists then you may try to run every list in separated thread or process - but it needs extra time to send data to thread or process - and it may not work as fast as you expect. And last idea is to use modules which may use functions created in C/C++ - like functions in `pandas`.

Comment: OR you would try to use special versions on Python - `Cython`, `Pypy` , `Nuitka` - whic may try to convert some code to C/C++